# instagram profile scraper - redirect to login page [PHP]

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

i have an script and its work without problems on local host.

here is my code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    //echo $username;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json=json_decode($result);
//var_dump($json);
$insta_profile_picture= $json->graphql->user->profile_pic_url_hd;

}
else{

}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type Your Username of Instagram " style="width:300px;height: 30px;border-radius: 4px;">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" style="width:300px;height: 35px;border-radius: 4px;">
    
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    if($insta_profile_picture){
//echo $insta_profile_picture;
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($insta_profile_picture));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData.'">';}
else{
    echo "something wrong";
}
}
else{
 echo "please select your username on top input for checking profile photo";
}
?>



</body>
</html>
```

but it not work on my server and with tracking the result i understand its redirect to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
please help me
tnx a lot for your helping

Comment: It's not the code... it worked a couple of time also from the url on chrome and then stopped and started redirecting to the login... - this is not a proper API call endpoint I think.

Comment: Hi awrefjm, this don't work because you are running the code from a server who is not logged as your account. Instagram don't allow to see users profile if are not logged

Comment: How i can get this information in my php code???

Comment: Can you explain to me??